# Tomcat Servlet GET not receiving parameters from Web client

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Web client (JavaScript) sending requests to a Servlet running on TOMCAT 8.5.

The request is sent using `$HTTP(req)` and, when examining the contents of `req` (i.e. in Chrome simply moving the cursor on top of it) it shows:

```
data:"request=%7B%....." 
headers: Object
  Content-Type: "application/text ; charset=UTF8"
method: "GET"
timeout: 10000
url: "http://localhost:8080/MyServlet/Dispatcher"
```

Notes:

1. The length of the encoded string is about 200 chars though I also tried with shorter strings,
2. I also tried `JSON` instead of `text` but same problem remains.

The servlet (for debugging purposes) checks if it received any parameter and, in case no parameter is found, it returns a default response.

I also added into the serlet, within the doGET method, the following piece of code:

```
    System.out.println("[DBG] - Printing all received parameters..."); 
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames(); 
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) { 
        String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement(); 
        System.out.println("[DBG] -       Received parameter name is: " + paramName); 
        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName); 
        for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) { 
            String paramValue = paramValues[i]; 
            System.out.println("[DBG] -       Received parameter value is: " + paramValue); 
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("[DBG] - End Printing all received parameters.");
```

which is expected to print whatever parameters it received regardless of names.

So far, I always get back the default response (meaning, no parameters received) and the printing to console shows:

```
[DBG] - Printing all received parameters...
[DBG] - End Printing all received parameters.
```

Again, meaning that no parameters were received.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit (following a received answer)

Within the servlet, I attempt to get the value of the parameter using the following declaration:

```
String  Web_Request = request.getParameter("request")   ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of passing the parameters as a string attached to the `data:` fields of the header, I set:

```
params:{request:'{<stringifyed JSON>}'}
```

Now, parameters are reaching the SERVLET.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a GET request, the body(data in your context) is ignored. If you want to sent as request parameter you have to append that to the url and try to get the value as `request.getParameter("request")` that should return you the string that you are adding.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Please see my addition to the original question.